# Gem Charlock_holmes installation error on Windows XP

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, failed-installation

I am trying to run bundler for my RoR app on a Windows machine (Windows XP). But, while downloading the gems, it stops at the `gem Charlock_Holmes` and gives the following error.

```
'Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
```

.

```
    C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
  checking for main() in -licui18n... no
   which: no brew in (.;C:\Devkit\bin;C:\Devkit\mingw\bin;C:\Ruby192\bin;C:\WINDOWS
 \system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\TCWIN4
  5\BIN)
 checking for main() in -licui18n... no


********************************************************************************
*******
*********** icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev) ****
*******
********************************************************************************
*******
*** extconf.rb failed ***
     Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

 Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
    --with-icu-dir
    --without-icu-dir
    --with-icu-include
    --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
    --with-icu-lib
    --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/lib
    --with-icui18nlib
    --without-icui18nlib
    --with-icui18nlib
    --without-icui18nlib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_
holmes-0.6.9 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9/ext/
charlock_holmes/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing charlock_holmes (0.6.9), and Bundler cannot c
ontinue.
Make sure that `gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.6.9'` succeeds before bundling'
```

Can you please help me figure out where the problem is ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same problem on Windows 7 and I cannot get around it.

Answer (score 2):

```
icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev)
```

As is stated in your question, you need `libicu-dev`. If you are using Cygwin you can install the package

[`cygwin.com/packages/x86/libicu-devel`](http://cygwin.com/packages/x86/libicu-devel)

Comment: What do I do if I'm not using Cygwin i.e. I just install ruby with RubyInstaller.